# How to change font style in App?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am currently developing an app using VS 2012 in HTML/JavaScript Platform. Now, I need to know how to change the font style of the App?

Comment: From Where you want to change font style? And What have you tried so far..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Windows Store app written using HTML/Javascript, you can set the global font family / style / weight in the file /css/default.css by setting a property in the #contenthost declaration.

for example...

```
#contenthost {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Copperplate Gothic Light';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: oblique;
}
```

would set your global UI font to Copperplate Gothic Light in bold with a style of oblique.

NOTE : I normally use XAML/C# so this may not be the best way to achieve this behaviour, but it does work.

Comment: i want to use TTF files, i ahve save my fonts in fonts folder. how should i use this TTF font ?

Answer (score 0):

See - 
[Embed / use custom font in Windows 8 Store apps](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/embed-use-custom-font-in-windows-8-store-apps-win8dev-winrt/)

Comment: thats not changing the fonts for whole app ?

Comment: changes my VS 2012 appearing fonts. not app font, i need to change app font. not VS appearing font

Comment: thats in the platform of XAML/C#. i am asking for javascript

Comment: goto channel9 and go through some beginner series